# How can I add a banner in my view?

Tags: android, android-layout

First, I have some view in `MainActivity.java` as follows:

```
CanvasMainMenu canvasMenu = new CanvasMainMenu(this);
setContentView(canvasMenu);
```

Class CanvasMainMenu extends `View` and I wanna add some banner into this view.

How can I add view of banner into my `CanvasMainMenu`?

Comment: what kind of banner? Did you register into Admob or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Could this help?

```
private static FrameLayout mFrameLayout = null;
private static MainView mMainView = null;

private static AdView mAdView = null;
//.....

protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
//.....
 AdView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14d3678cfc9fb7");

 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
 adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

    mFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(getApplicationContext());

    mMainView = new MainView(getApplicationContext());

 mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
 mAdView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
//.....
mFrameLayout.addView(mAdView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

}

public void setOverlayView(int gameMode) {
mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: what is mFrameLayout? How can I get that?

Comment: `mFrameLayout` clearly looks like the root of your layout, which he states to be a `FrameLayout`, thus the variable name. The `//.....` could be where you find the current view.